# How to run composer from anywhere?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have just installed composer in my `/usr/bin` folder, so when from that folder I run `php composer.phar` I get the help info about composer. But, when I try to run the same from other folder I get `Could not open input file: composer.phar`.

How to call `php composer.phar` from every where without problems?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

composer.phar can be ran on its own, no need to prefix it with `php`. This should solve your problem (being in the difference of bash's $PATH and php's include_path).

Comment: You can also rename it to just composer and then you can simply do `composer install`.

Comment: my composer.phar is install. (I Chekced using php composer.phar) But, i'm not getting the location. How to find path of composer.phar location? I'm using UBUNTU.

Comment: If you can run `php composer.phar`, then it's probably in your current directory.

Comment: I think you want a global access to your composer.phar. Move it and make an alias : 
`sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/` then `alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer.phar'`.

Comment: I did a `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`. After that I can use just `composer install` anywhere.

Answer (score 122):

You can do a [global installation](https://github.com/composer/composer#global-installation-of-composer-manual) ([archived guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20131106081341/http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally)):

> *Since Composer works with the current working directory it is possible to install it in a system-wide way.*
>
> 1. *Change into a directory in your path like*
>
>    **`cd /usr/local/bin`**
> 2. *Get Composer*
>
>    **`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`**
> 3. *Make the phar executable*
>
>    **`chmod a+x composer.phar`**
> 4. *Change into a project directory*
>
>    **`cd /path/to/my/project`**
> 5. *Use Composer as you normally would*
>
>    **`composer.phar install`**
> 6. *Optionally you can rename the* **`composer.phar`** *to* **`composer`** *to make it easier*

**Update**: Sometimes you can't or don't want to download at `/usr/local/bin` (some have experienced user permissions issues or restricted access), in this case, open a terminal an try this steps:

```
$ curl -sS http://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --filename=composer

$ chmod a+x composer

$ sudo mv composer /usr/local/bin/composer
```

**Update 2**: For Windows 10 and PHP 7 I recommend [this tutorial](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/installing-php-7-and-composer-on-windows-10) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20201130201057/https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/installing-php-7-and-composer-on-windows-10)). Personally, I installed [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017 x64](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/VC_redist.x64.exe) before PHP 7.3 VC15 x64 Non Thread Safe version (check which versions of both in the [PHP for Windows](https://windows.php.net/download/) page, side menu). Read carefully and maybe the enable-extensions section could differ (`extension=curl` instead of `extension=php_curl.dll`). Works like a charm.

Comment: They do not note that you need to rename the file for it to be called with just `composer` - good note here.

Comment: @AndrewAtkinson Alternatively you can rename before download with `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --filename=composer`

Comment: Just want to say thanks for this. I've had trouble understanding the underlying logic, and getcomposer.org itself doesn't do a very good job at explaining this, so thanks! I got it working.

Comment: Nice to know that creating an "alias" is not necessary when installing to /user/local/bin

Answer (score 30):

## How to run Composer From Anywhere (on MacOS X) via Terminal

**Background:**

Actually in getComposer website it clearly states that, install the Composer by using the following curl command,

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer |php
```

And it certainly does what it's intended to do. And then it says to move the **composer.phar** to the directory **/usr/local/bin/composer** and then composer will be available Globally, by using the following command line in terminal!

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

**Question:**

So the problem which leads me to Google over it is when I executed the above line in Mac OS X Terminal, it said that, Permission denied. Like as follows:

```
mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer: Permission denied
```

**Answer:**

Following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14484786/1752988) led me to the solution like a charm and I'm thankful to that. The thing I just missed was **sudo** command before the above stated "Move" command line.
Now my Move command is as follows:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
Password:
```

It directly prompts you to authenticate yourself and see if you are authorized. So if you enter a valid password, then the Moving will be done, and you can just check if composer is globally installed, by using the following line.

```
composer about
```

I hope this answer helped you to broaden your view and finally resolve your problem.

Cheers!

Comment: > And then it says to move the composer.phar to the directory /usr/local/bin/composer
`/usr/local/bin/composer` is not a directory; it is the new name for the file that would be called `composer.phar` prior to that.

Comment: Worked for me on macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 23):

First install the composer like mentioned in the composer [installation documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally). I just added here for reference.

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

and then move the file to '/usr/local/bin'.

`sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

Try to run `composer -V`. If you get a output like `Composer version` followed by the version number then the composer is installed successfully.

If you get any output like `composer: command not found` means use the following command to create a alias for the composer. So it will be executed globally.

**`alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer'`**

Now if you run `composer -V` means you will get the output as `Composer Version` followed by the version number.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 9):

Just move it to `/usr/local/bin` folder and remove the extension

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: Just What I Needed, Thank You

Answer (score 8):

Simply run this command for installing composer globally

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Comment: This solve my issue with asking for sudoer password. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For MAC and LINUX use the following procedure:

Add the directory where composer.phar is located to you PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/yourdirectory
```

and then rename composer.phar to composer:

```
mv composer.phar composer
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple global install to run it from anywhere

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

The https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally website recommends this way.  Worked well on Ubuntu 14.04 no problem.
This way you don't need to do as an example `php compomser.phar show` , you just do `composer show` , in any directory you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

For running it from other location you can use the composer program that come with the program. It is basically a bash script. If you don't have it you can create one by simply copying the following code into a text file

```
#!/bin/sh

dir=$(d=$(dirname "$0"); cd "$d" && pwd)

if command -v 'cygpath' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  dir=$(cygpath -m $dir);
fi

dir=$(echo $dir | sed 's/ /\ /g')
php "${dir}/composer.phar" $*
```

Then save the file inside your bin folder and name it composer without any file extension. Then add the bin folder to your environment variable f

Answer (score 0):

Some of this may be due to the OS your server is running. I recently did a migration to a new hosting environment running Ubuntu. Adding this alias `alias composer="/path/to/your/composer"` to .bashrc or .bash_aliases didn't work at first because of two reasons:

The server was running csh, not bash, by default. To check if this is an issue in your case, run `echo $0`. If the what is returned is `-csh` you will want to change it to bash, **since some processes run by Composer will fail using csh/tcsh**.

To change it, first check if bash is available on your server by running `cat /etc/shells`. If, in the list returned, you see `bin/bash`, you can change the default to bash by running `chsh -s /bin/csh`.

Now, at this point, you should be able to run Composer, but normally, on Ubuntu, you will have to load the script at every session by sourcing your Bash scripts by running `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile`. This is because, in most cases, Ubuntu won't load your Bash script, since it loads `.profile` as the default script.

To load your Bash scripts when you open a session, try adding this to your .profile (this is if your Bash script is .bashrc—modify accordingly if .bash_profile or other):

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

To test, close your session and reload. If it's working properly, running `composer -v` or `which composer` should behave as expected.