# having trouble installing composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I am installing composer with the following cammand

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

But I am keep getting below **error message**

```
Zafars-MacBook-Pro:etc zafarsaleem$ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
#!/usr/bin/env php
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The detect_unicode setting must be disabled.
Add the following to the end of your `php.ini`:
detect_unicode = Off

A php.ini file does not exist. You will have to create one.
```

How can I install composer be removing above error?

**EDIT**

```
Zafars-MacBook-Pro:etc zafarsaleem$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

**Latest Edit**

After some research I found that `php.ini` file which is being used is in `/etc/php.ini`. However, when I checked this file in `/etc` folder it wasn't there. `/etc` folder contained `php.ini.default` folder which linked to `/private/etc/php.ini.default`. So I added `detect_unicode = Off` in `/etc/php.ini.default` and the renamed this file to `php.ini`. Now when I execute below command

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

OR

```
sudo curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Then I get following errors

```
Zafars-MacBook-Pro:/ zafarsaleem$ sudo curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
Download failed: failed to open stream: Permission denied
Downloading...
Download failed: failed to open stream: Permission denied
Downloading...
Download failed: failed to open stream: Permission denied
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

How can I install composer on my computer and remove above problems? Please help

Comment: Whats wrong with the message? What concrete problem do you have?

Comment: It does not install composer. I need to add `detect_unicode = Off` in my `php.ini` file which I did but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: You edited the correct `php.ini`? Every SAPI use their own one.

Comment: I edited the one in `etc/`. That is the one which is loaded.

Comment: After I run `php -i | grep ini` I get above edited display from where I can get that php.ini is loaded from `etc/`

Comment: Try `php --ini` for a more detailed output

Comment: @KingCrunch see my second edit above

Comment: have you edited the right php.ini? You probably have a separate one for php-cli

Comment: @KingCrunch Please see my latest updated post. I added some more steps that I did but this time I getting different errors while installing composer.

Comment: @shanethehat Please see my latest updated post. I added some more steps that I did but this time I getting different errors while installing composer.

Comment: @x4ph4r Soooo... What is misleading with "permission denied"? Download the latest phar manually.

Comment: Composer is satisfied that you have your settings correct. No idea why it would deny permission, but you can download the phar manually from here: https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar (right click, save as...)

Comment: Download failed because your current directory was "/" and you didnt have write permissions there. Please see my instructions below, which i tested on OSX 10.8.2 .

Comment: I think the issue was that I was issuing command `curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` in a folder which did not have write privileges. Below answer helped me to solve this issue.

Comment: I was having this same issue and I fixed my problem by `cd Users` to my Users directory and then into my own user account directory `cd <username>`. I did this on Mac. Everything installed perfectly fine when I got to my `~ <username>$`  directory. In case this helps anyone. I ran @Andreyco's command from below.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

To download / install on MacOSX, you can do the [following steps](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally) *or* try the [homebrew](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally-on-osx-via-homebrew-) steps below:

1. Goto a directory you can write to:

   cd ~
2. get composer:

   curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
3. move composer into a bin directory in your $PATH var:

   sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
4. double check composer works

   composer about
5. (optional) Update composer:

   sudo composer self-update

**[Homebrew](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally-on-osx-via-homebrew-)**

```
brew update
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install php55-intl
brew install homebrew/php/composer
```

Comment: I had to run the solution from @Andreyco instead of step 2.

Comment: Worked for me as well on Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: At the risk of sounding stupid...where do you write these commands? Terminal? a PHP page? I'm new to this and have literally no idea where to start

Comment: @jampez77 , yes in a terminal  .

Comment: note in recent versions of OSX Mavericks(10.9.2), I used    
`sudo mv composer.phar /bin/composer`    

to allow it to be ran from "composer" instead of "composer.phar". Hope that helps save you 20 minutes.

Comment: @cpk is there something superior to moveing to  `/bin/composer` vs `/usr/local/bin/composer`   ?

Comment: @MikeGraf  No, I just wasn't able to move composer.phar to `/usr/local/bin` as it isn't a directory on my machine, but a file itself. I think there are some new safeguards in place on newer versions of OSX to forbid access `/usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: I was getting permission denied error when updating the composer.
point 5 helped me out. Thanks @MikeGraf

Comment: Works in Linux Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, too

Answer (score 30):

Try this instead and change the setting on the fly, just for this command

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -d detect_unicode=Off
```

Comment: But this needs to run `php composer.phar`

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu Vivid 15.04. Try:
Steps:

1. Open terminal and write:  ***sudo su*** and press Enter.
2. Paste this: ***curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php*** and
   press Enter. (This install composer, Wait to finish)
3. And Finaly Write **exit**

Note: Sorry, my English is bad :(

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error. I ended up adding sudo to the php side and it worked for me.

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
```

Answer (score 2):

In case if you dont have curl in your system, you can still install composer using the following command

Go to a directory where you can write,

```
cd yourDirectory

php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -d detect_unicode=off
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin

Run this command and it will work, so i think :D