# Install october cms with composer on raspbian 8 (raspberry b+)

Tags: php, mysql, linux, octobercms

yesterday i started to install raspbian on my raspberry b+ to create a development machine to test October cms.

I install: 
apache 2
php - 5.6.14
mysql 
phpmyadmin

Then i follow this link to installa october cms:

https://adrianmejias.com/blog/post/october-cms
https://octobercms.com/docs/console/commands

But i have encouter different problems. I installed composer as root then try to create project to pull the october dev-master.

I received this error: 
`"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory' in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/ symfony/console/Application.php:954"`

I solved the first problem with this:
[having trouble installing composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437588/having-trouble-installing-composer)

I tried again to instyall all but when composer pull down symfony files there was a root problem, i think due to the fact root took all allocated memory i do and "df -i" and i see "/dev/root have inodes 100% but dev/root have 12000mb" of space so i didn't understand.

Try so to install again composer as pi but without success!

Now i try to mysql -version and also have problem with mysql.

```
"ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"
```

I think it's all correlated with memory limit (that is a good excercise in this case bacause ipothetycal vps have this problem), but i can't figured out what is this.

Have some suggestions? Did i made mistake with swap file? or another?

Thanks
Gabriele

Answer (score 0):

If still interested, try increasing the swap size:

```
sudo nano /etc/dphys-swapfile
```

change this line: `CONF_SWAPSIZE=100` to this: `CONF_SWAPSIZE=512`, than:

```
sudo dphys-swapfile setup
sudo dphys-swapfile swapon
```