# Regenerate autoload.php in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have autoload.php with this code

```
<?php

// autoload.php generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit8be239f5caef32db03f87bb271ed6012::getLoader();
```

but when I access to localhost

```
Fatal error: Class 'ComposerAutoloaderInit8be239f5caef32db03f87bb271ed6012' not found in /home/sebastian/Development/PHP/miciudad/vendor/autoload.php on line 10
```

Yesterday this work and I didn update.

If I run `php composer.phar install` will it work and generate the correct  autoload.php?

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It should. Also `php composer.phar dump-autoload` should do the job.
As stated in [the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-):

> If you need to update the autoloader because of new classes in a classmap package for example, you can use dump-autoload to do that without having to go through an install or update.

Comment: Ugh, why did they name it "dump", bit counterintuitive. Should be "generate" instead. Oh well, thanks!

Comment: ...without prefix: `composer dump-autoload`.  How to: [how-to-run-composer-from-anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333230/how-to-run-composer-from-anywhere)