# Can somebody tell me the exact process of installing composer correctly?

Tags: php, installation, composer-php, yii2

I tried installing it for windows and ubuntu in either case i got the same error:Could not open input file: composer.phar

I am not messing with the env path variables.
I have openssl uncomented in php.ini.
It will be great if any assistance is given by a YII expert.
As i am unable to get the YII 2.0 working.

Comment: See my answer; I'm assuming that you're running Composer with `php composer.phar <command>`. If not, please tell us how you're getting the error.

Comment: By the way, it seems like this is a duplicate question. See [could not input open file: composer.phar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20769980/1001110), [Could not open input file: composer.phar error in symfony2 using wamp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21670709/1001110) and [How to run composer from anywhere?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11333230/1001110), for instance. Also see https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1116. Have you even looked up the error message on Google, or did you simply create a question on Stack Overflow without any prior research?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to use Composer: either download the file `composer.phar` (phar stands for PHP Archive) and place it in your working directory, or install it globally.

If you downloaded the phar, you need to run Composer commands like this:

```
php composer.phar <command>
```

But if you installed it globally (by running `Composer-Setup.exe` on Windows, or placing `composer.phar` in `/usr/local/bin/composer` on Linux), you need to run it like this:

```
composer <command>
```

(where you replace `<command>` with one of the available commands, such as `install`, `update` or `self-update`)

It seems like you have installed Composer globally, but are running it with `php composer.phar`. Because the file `composer.phar` does not exist in your current directory, it returns the 'Could not open input file' error.

For more information, see the chapter '[Using Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#using-composer)' in the Composer documentation.

Comment: Nic when i type composer i get the composer dialogue and the help section its only on using the composer.phar i get the above error.And yes i am using it along with php as asked by you.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say here.