# Can't use php or composer as commands on opensuse

Tags: php, linux, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm a new linux user been trying to install laravel on opensuse. It took me a while because of permissions but was able to install it to a directory then moving it to htdocs. The problem is I can't run php command so I always use this

```
user@linux:/opt/lampp/bin> ./php -v
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Feb  1 2017 01:41:45)

user@linux:/opt/lampp/bin> ./php /opt/lampp/composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel /any_directory_path/blog
```

now i'm trying to run

```
php artisan serve
```

But i get this

```
If 'php' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

but I get

```
Package 'php5-cli' not found.
```

So how to fix this issue to be able to use php and composer as commands in the console

Comment: Since when does SuSE have `apt-get`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the cli version of php wont be enough if you actually want to use this beyond development, you need to install as an apache module. There also doesn't seem to be a specific cli package on opensuse which is why you are getting this error.

`php artisan serve` is intended just for development purposes, it uses the inbuit php web server, which for many reasons should note be used on production servers (those used by actual users, available on the internet or even a private network).

The reason it's erroring is the php binary is not in your path - if you specify the full path it would run: `/opt/lampp/bin/php artisan serve`

You could add this to your path - this question/answer covers how to do this well: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

You probably want to edit your `~/.profile` file by editing or adding the following line `PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin/` which would mean any commands inside /opt/lamp/bin/ would work without the full path needing to be entered each time.

Try `sudo apt-get install php5`

[This tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-lamp-stack-on-opensuse_42.1/) should walk you through all the steps.

Also worth noting there is now php7 - are you specifically installing the older version for a reason?

Try `sudo apt-get install php7`

There are a number of modules which you may also require, you can see available packages on [opensuse website](https://software.opensuse.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=php7-&search_devel=false&search_unsupported=false&baseproject=openSUSE%3ALeap%3A42.2)

From comments it sounds like you will need openssl and phar at least, these can be installed like so:

`sudo apt-get install php7-openssl php7-phar`

Looking at the [requirements for laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation)

> - PHP >= 5.6.4
> - OpenSSL PHP Extension
> - PDO PHP Extension
> - Mbstring PHP Extension
> - Tokenizer PHP Extension
> - XML PHP Extension

You will also need to run:

`sudo apt-get install php7-pdo php7-mbstring php7-tokenizer php7-xml`

---

Regarding composer you should be able to get this installed by running

```
/opt/lampp/composer.phar install
```

If this doesn't solve it for you then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333230/how-to-run-composer-from-anywhere) should provide you with various options to try:

Comment: I can use php as a command but there's a problem: I used "/opt/lampp/bin/php /opt/lampp/composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog" it was installed but got an error: "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in PATH HERE/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 477
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255" Then: "php artisan
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in PATH HERE/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 477

Comment: and still can't use 'composer' as a command too. Thanks for your help so far and hope you can help me fixing this all.

Comment: The syntax error sounds like it may be todo with the php version, as I doubt you have a copy of Illuminate/Foundation with a syntax error. if you type `/opt/lampp/bin/php -v` it will tell you your version, if it is less than 5.3 then this may well be your problem, but even if it is less than 5.6 then you are running an unsupported version that may have security issues.

Comment: @PHPUser I have updated my answer with some help on the composer side of things.

Comment: remved php5 installed php 7 and "/opt/lampp/composer.phar install" returns "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Phar' not found in /opt/lampp/composer.phar:23"

Comment: That removed composer my bad i'll try to install it again then try what you mentioned

Comment: trying to install composer  php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" but i get "PHP Warning:  copy(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in Command line code on line 1
PHP Warning:  copy(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in Command line code on line 1
PHP Warning:  copy(https://getcomposer.org/installer): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1"

Comment: also tried "sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer" but I get "Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly. Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again: The phar extension is missing. Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar. The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible. If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl"

Comment: you need to install the openssl and the phar modules try `apt-get install php7-openssl  php7-phar`

Comment: I have updated the answer with a link to laravel requirements and the other modules you will likely need.